# How find this limit $\lim_{x\to 1}\Gamma{(1-x)}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}x\right)$

Tags: limits

Find this limit
$$I=\lim_{x \to 1}\Gamma\left(1 - x\right)\cos\left({\pi \over 2}\,x\right)$$

where 
$\Gamma{(x)}$ is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

My idea: let $u=1-x$,then
$$I=\lim_{u\to 0}\Gamma{(u)}\sin{u}$$
then I can't,Thank you

Comment: $I=\lim_{u\to0}\Gamma(u)\sin(\frac{\pi u}{2})=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

...And $\sin(au)\sim au$ while $\Gamma(u)=\Gamma(1+u)/u\sim\Gamma(1)/u$ hence $\Gamma(u)\sin(au)\to$ $____$.

Comment: To be used with $u=1-x$ and $a=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(1-x)\cos\left(\frac\pi2x\right)
&=\frac{\Gamma(2-x)}{1-x}\sin\left(\frac\pi2(1-x)\right)\\[6pt]
&=\Gamma(2-x)\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi2(1-x)\right)}{1-x}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can develop each term of the product as a Taylor series built around $x=1$. You then obtain, limiting the developements to the first terms in $(1 - x)$,

$\Gamma(1 - x) = -\gamma + 1 / (1 - x)$

$\cos(\pi x / 2) =  \pi(1 - x) / 2$

So the product becomes

$\pi / 2 - \gamma \pi (1 - x) / 2$

Comment: Please read [the MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: @robjohn. I am sorry for not being able to use LaTeX or MathJax. Please have a look to my profile. Thanks for editing. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

use the reflection property of gamma function $$\Gamma (x) \Gamma (1-x)=\frac{\pi x}{\sin (\pi x)}$$ therefore the expression becomes $$\frac{\pi x \cos (\frac{\pi x}{2})}{\Gamma (x)\sin (\pi x)}$$ now substitute $$\sin (\pi x)=2\sin (\frac{\pi x}{2})\cos (\frac{\pi x}{2})$$ to get the limit as $\frac{\pi}{2}$